# i want a simple validation with Javascript for my Contact form

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Hello dear Developers,

i have a simple contact form with HTML and CSS and i want simple validation with Javascript (and Localstorage) for Name, Email and comment section. Hier is my code but the JS does not work.
I have validation function for name and email but they doesnt work.

Can you help me?

HTML:

```
            <input type="text" id="name_key" class="input-kontakt" name="name" tabindex="1" placeholder="Name:*" required>

            <input type="email" id="mail_key" class="input-kontakt" name="email" tabindex="2" placeholder="Email:*" required>

            <textarea name="massage" id="message_key" class="input-kontakt" tabindex="3" maxlength="200" placeholder="Nachricht:*" required></textarea>
            
            <div class="error"></div>
            <br>
            
            <button id="button_key" class="button" type="submit" tabindex="4">Senden</button>

    </form>
```

Java Script:

```
const name_key = document.getElementById("name_key");
const mail_key = document.getElementById("mail_key");
const message_key = document.getElementById("message_key");
const button_key = document.getElementById("button_key");

function validMail (mail_key) {
    return /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/.test(mail_key);
}

function validateName() {
    if (name_key === null) {
      error.innerHTML = 'Name kann nicht leer sein';
      return false;
    } else if (name_key < characters.length < 3) {
      error.innerHTML = 'Name muss mehr als 3 karakter sein';
      return false;
    }
  }
  
function validateEmail() {
    if (mail_key === null) {
        error.innerHTML = 'Email kann nicht leer sein';
        return false;
    } else if (mail_key < characters.length < 5) {
        error.innerHTML = 'Email muss mehr als 3 karakter sein';
        return false;
    }else if (validMail() = false){
        error.innerHTML = 'Bitte nutzen Sie richtige Email-Format';
        return false;
    }
  }


button_key.onclick = function () {
    const name = name_key.value;
    const mail = mail_key.value;
    const message = message_key.value;

    
        if (name && mail && message) 
        {
            localStorage.setItem("name_key", name);
            localStorage.setItem("mail_key", mail);
            localStorage.setItem("message_key", message);
            localStorage.setItem("kontaktaufnahme", name + " ;" + mail  + " ;" + message);
            window.confirm("Wir melden uns!");
        }    
        else{ 
            window.confirm("Leider fehlen Angaben!");
        }

};
```

Comment: One thing I want to point out is that you've created functions for validation but you are never using those functions to validate the data. You just have to call these validation functions inside the button `onclick` and if everything is okay only then set values in local storage.

Comment: How should i call them? i mean. i should write a if for this case and call them

Comment: how should i edit my if-statement

Comment: You can update your functions to return `true` if everything is fine. And then just after the `if (name && mail && message)` condition write another `if` condition within which you can call all the functions with `&&` between them.

Comment: doesn't work yet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const name_key = document.getElementById("name_key");
const mail_key = document.getElementById("mail_key");
const message_key = document.getElementById("message_key");
const button_key = document.getElementById("button_key");


function validMail (email) {
    const pattern = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return pattern.test(email);
}

function validateName(name) {
    if (name == "") {
      error.innerHTML = 'Name kann nicht leer sein';
      return false;
    } else if (name.length < 3) {
      error.innerHTML = 'Name muss mehr als 3 karakter sein';
      return false;
    }
        return true;
    }

  



function validateEmail(email) {
    if (email == "") {
        error.innerHTML = 'Email kann nicht leer sein';
        return false;
    } else if (email.length < 4) {
        error.innerHTML = 'Email muss mehr als 4 karakter sein';
        return false;
    }else if (!validMail(email)){
        error.innerHTML = 'Bitte nutzen Sie richtige Email-Format';
        return false;
    }
        return true;
    }


function validateMsg(message) {
    if (message == "") {
        error.innerHTML = 'Bitte schreiben Sie Ihren Nachricht.';
        return false;
    }
        return true;
    }
    



button_key.onclick = function () {
    const name = name_key.value;
    const email = mail_key.value;
    const message = message_key.value;


            if ( validateName(name) && validateEmail(email) && validateMsg(message) ){
                localStorage.setItem("name_key", name);
                localStorage.setItem("mail_key", email);
                localStorage.setItem("message_key", message);
                localStorage.setItem("kontaktaufnahme", name + " ;" + email  + " ;" + message);
                window.confirm("Wir melden uns!");
            }
        
        
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things missing:

1. The `validateName` and `validateEmail` functions are never called. Thus, their results can never be read.
2. The `validateName` and `validateEmail` functions don't check the actual `value` from the inputs, but the inputs themselves.

Make sure that you allow both function allow a value being passed to those functions. Try to visualize it as handing a word (the value) over to your friend ( the function) who will return you the answer if the word is good or not (your result).

Also in JavaScript checking the length of a string is can be done by reading the `length` property of that string. Then compare that length to a number.

```
const name_key = document.getElementById("name_key");
const mail_key = document.getElementById("mail_key");
const message_key = document.getElementById("message_key");
const button_key = document.getElementById("button_key");

function validateName(value) {
  if (value === '') {
    error.innerHTML = 'Name kann nicht leer sein';
    return false;
  } else if (value.length < 3) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Name muss mehr als 3 karakter sein';
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function validMail(value) {
  return /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/.test(value);
}

function validateEmail(value) {
  if (value === '') {
    error.innerHTML = 'Email kann nicht leer sein';
    return false;
  } else if (value.length < 5) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Email muss mehr als 3 karakter sein';
    return false;
  } else if (validMail(value)) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Bitte nutzen Sie richtige Email-Format';
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
  
button_key.onclick = function () {
  const name = name_key.value;
  const mail = mail_key.value;
  const message = message_key.value;

  const isValidName = validateName(name);
  const isValidEmail = validateEmail(mail);

  if (isValidName && isValidEmail) {
    // Name and email are valid.
  }
};
```